# Case-Insensitive String Comparison in Entity Framework queries

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I would like to do case insensitive comparison. I have tried several approaches, but none of them seem to be working:

```
var userInfo = _context.SYSUSERs.AsNoTracking()
                       .FirstOrDefault(u => u.LOGINID.Equals(userId, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));

// returns null object.

var userInfo = _context.SYSUSERs.AsNoTracking()
                       .FirstOrDefault(u => string.Equals(u.LOGINID, userId, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));

// Exception thrown:
// System.ArgumentException: Incorrect number of arguments supplied for call to method 'Boolean Equals(System.String, System.String, System.StringComparison)'
```

The database is Oracle.

`Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework` version 6.122.XXX

Comment: Have you tried trimming each string or using .ToLower / .ToUpper on both strings?

Comment: .ToLower/.ToUpper is working. I am concerned about the performance if I use those.

Comment: @Shaggy Have you done a trace of the SQL being submitted to the server?

Comment: There is no unnecessary performance hit with ToLower/ToUpper. EF needs to tell the SQL engine to compare the two strings in the same case. The only hack I can think of is that if this system is the owner of the data and inserts *all* relevant data as Upper Case for instance, you could get away with just the ToUpper on the variable side meaning the SQL run would not be adjusting Case and could leverage indexes. However, any data inserted that isn't upper-case would not be matched.

Comment: Case sensitivity is controlled by the *column's collation* and the most common collations are case *in*sensitive. Are you sure you need to chance the case at all? That's not a trivial change as it affects whether you can use an index or not